# MySQL select different values as different columns in a same table?

Tags: mysql, select

I use a table `Votes` to store the likes/dislikes for user posts (`Posts`). Now I want to select the number of a post likes and dislikes. Currently the query is as below:

```
SELECT p.*, count(v1.id) AS Likes, count(v2.id) AS Dislikes FROM Posts p
LEFT JOIN Votes v1 ON v1.post_id=p.id AND v1.status=1
LEFT JOIN Votes v2 ON v2.post_id=p.id AND v2.status=2
WHERE p.id=123
```

Is there a better approach that the two cases can be combined into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CASE` and `SUM` in a single `JOIN`

Something like

```
SELECT  p.*, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN v1.status=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Likes, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN v1.status=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dislikes FROM Posts p
LEFT JOIN Votes v1 ON v1.post_id=p.id 
WHERE p.id=123
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use conditional sum for this

```
select
SELECT p.*,
sum(v.status=1) as `Likes`,
sum(v.status=2) as `Dislikes`
from Posts p
LEFT JOIN Votes v ON v.post_id=p.id 
where p.id=123
```